# What is the difference between sourceCompatibility 8 and 11? What happens when they are set to different values?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-activity, source-compatibility

When I target Android API level 21 what I set as `sourceCompatibility` 11 or 8 and what's the differences in my build gradle I always set it like that

```
 compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

but on android studio Electric Eel it says:
`Starting with Android Gradle plugin 7.4.0-alpha04, AGP ships wth JVM 11 bytecode.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you set your compile options to

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}
```

you will be able to compile with Java 11 language features

Comment: deos this effect on mobile devices or no?

Comment: No, it does not. It only changes what version of the Java language you can use to create your project.